# Pass Variables Between Pages in Apex

Tags: oracle-apex

I have an interactive report, page 4, which displays a list of projects. Each row that is displayed has a check box. When I select the check box for a specific row, I want to go to page 10 which displays a list of documents which can be allocated to the project. To do this, I need to pass the project_id, from the projects page to the documents page. 
I have created P10_PROJECT_ID on page 10 to receive the project if
I have created a submit button to be clicked once a project has been selected. In the page button processing I have set up the 'Action when button is clicked' as
Action: Redirect to Page in this application
Page: 10
Set these items: P10_PROJECT_ID
with these values:  &PROJECT_ID.

However the project id is not being passed from page 4 to page 10. If I change &PROJECT_ID. to the value 101, the value is passed

Please can someone help explain where I have gone wrong when trying to pass the variable for project id?

Thanks

Tracey

Comment: Why do you want to use a checkbox as a column link? That serves no purpose. You can easily achieve your requirement by specifying a column link on the report.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question, you need pass 1 project_id.
In region source of your report change your select like:

```
SELECT name, description,
'<a href="f?p=app_id:10:&APP_SESSION.::::P10_PROJECT_ID:'|| id ||'" target="_blank">display DOC</a>' link
FROM your_table
```

you will get link to 10 page in your report (`id` value transmits to `P10_PROJECT_ID`)